# How to assign one function to all items in the collection?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

How to assign one function to all items in the collection?

I have one setInterval function and I want to assign it to all HTML elements in the collection

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // THIS IS MY FUNCTION
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var number = parseInt(this.innerText, 10);
    number++;
    this.innerText = number;
  }, 1000);

  // this is my attempt TO assign one function to all items in the collection
  var counter = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

  for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    counter[i].addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", interval);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-number="100">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="500">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="600">0</div>
```

I want each individual html element with class '.counter' to have it's own function named 'interval'

Comment: `interval` is *not* a reference to the function

Comment: George is correct. `interval` refers to the interval. The function inside is an inline anonymous function that can't be referenced. Can you please take a step back and describe more broadly what you're trying to achieve? This is somewhat of an XY Question; that is, you're asking about your *solution* instead of your *problem*.

Comment: I want to build a counter section on my website, with 3 separate counters inside running until they reach data-number (data-number is inside each div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a reference for the function, `window.setInterval` returns just a numeric id to possibly clear the timer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var fn = function() {
    setInterval(() => {
      var number = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
       number++;
       this.innerHTML= number;
    }, 1000);
   }

  var counter = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    fn.call(counter[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-number="100">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="500">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="600">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're assigning the a new event on the `DOMContentLoaded` trigger AFTER it's been called (you are on the function `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",`).

Second, your `interval` is not referencing the function but the result of the first call. You need to create a function (by adding `function() {}` or `() =>`) and pass the HTML node to it (the `counter`)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

      var interval = (counter) => setInterval(function() {
        var number = parseInt(counter.innerText, 10);
        number++;
        counter.innerText = number;
      }, 1000);


      var counter = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
      for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
        interval(counter[i])
      }
 });
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-number="100">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="500">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="600">0</div>
```

---

Now with a little more of rewriting:

```js
const interval = (counter) => setInterval(() => {
  counter.innerText = parseInt(counter.innerText, 10)+1;
}, 1000);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.counter')).forEach(c => {
    interval(c);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-number="100">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="500">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-number="600">0</div>
```

Comment: You could also simplify this to `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => [...document.querySelectorAll('.counter')].forEach(c => interval(c)))` if you are going for code golf.

Comment: Haha nice catch, i wasn't trying to go on extrem code golf but at least remove variable assignation when they are not needed

Comment: "your `interval` is not referencing the function but the result of the first call"....wrong